# Who is the best writer among statisticians?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I'd like to learn their writing style.
Could you recommend a good writer statistician?

Comment: I have voted to close as this question solicits either opinions (person A's good writer need to be everyone's good writer), or list like answers; there is no true answer. Such questions are not a good fit for *any* [se] site. Hopefully this explains why people are voting to close?

Comment: I like this question, and am disappointed that we won't be seeing any answers to it.